# Eloquent: use a modificator in WhereIn

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

in my code i've create a modificator and generate the column chiave_composita. If i run this code i've obtain the data

```
TransazioniOrigine::all()->pluck('chiave_composita')->toArray()
```

but if i use this code

```
    $origine = TransazioniOrigine::all()->pluck('chiave_composita')->toArray();
    $destinazione = Transazioni::all()->pluck('transazioneKey')->toArray();
    $diff = array_diff($origine, $destinazione);
    dd(TransazioniOrigine::whereIn('chiave_composita', $diff)->get());
```

i have this errror:

Il nome di colonna 'chiave_composita' non è valido. (SQL: select * from [vwTransazioni] where [chiave_composita] in (1515152021011110))

how can i solve this issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** use `whereIn` with accessors. The database doesn't know about them.

What you **can** do is `filter` the resulting collection.

```php
TransazioniOrigine::get()->filter(fn($t) => in_array($t->chiave_composita, $diff));
```