# laravel ancestors how to use in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

My data `phone` data was serialised stored in the meta column and i trying to use Eloquent ancestors unserialised the `phone` data for query purpose.

Eloquent

```
protected $appends = ['meta', 'phone'];

public function getMetaAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['meta'];
}

public function getPhoneAttribute()
{
    return Arr::get(@unserialize($this->attributes['meta']),'phone');
}
```

The code above able to pull out the `phone` data in the data structure like example

```
 {
        "id": 3264,
        "ref_num": "INV-2834",
        "phone": 0123456789
 },
```

I 'm trying to use `phone` in where clause for checking purpose but the sql will show unknown column for `phone`.

Code

```
 public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = Sale::orderBy($request->sort_by, $request->sort_type)
                    ->where('phone', 1);

        return $query;
    }
```

How could I inject `phone` as fake column in order to use in query where clause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent: use a modificator in WhereIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65675483/eloquent-use-a-modificator-in-wherein) Accessors can't be used inside an SQL query.

Comment: @IGP Thanks for your explanation and the answer. I will try it out.